# How to execute large sql file (800MB) with SSMS 2019? My sql file is database backup

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I done database backup from remote server.
Here i find instructions

[How can I backup a remote SQL Server database to a local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942207/how-can-i-backup-a-remote-sql-server-database-to-a-local-drive)

Now i can not open and execute file in SSMS because this file is too big.

I find examples how execute with CMD. But here you must to write database destination. And my sql script creates a new database.

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Conclusion: I do not know how to execute properly my sql file.

Comment: Use `master` as your connection db then.

Comment: I used just myServer. Without db name

Answer (score 1):

I used just myServer. Without db name

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -i C:\myScript.sql
```