# Copy / Paste .mdf and .ldf restoration file on my local machine

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have SQL Server Express running on my machine, and I would like to create a backup of a database and restore this backup on my local machine so that I can use the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files locally.

I have a small C# program that manages this database and allows me to execute the backup creation and restore requests. However, when I want to copy/paste the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files locally, I don't have access rights. Only the administrator account and the SQL Service have access.

Is there a way to perform the restore locally without sharing a folder with the server?

Backup method:

```
string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + "Database" + "] TO DISK='" + "\\\\srv-vm\\PJDB\\Backup\\Database.bak" +  "'";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
{
  if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  {
      con.Open();
  }

  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Restore method:

```
SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
ServerConnection con = new 
ServerConnection(objconnection.DataSource.ToString());
Server server = new Server(con);

Restore _dataBase = new Restore();

_dataBase.Database = "db";
_dataBase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
_dataBase.Devices.AddDevice("\\\\srv-vm\\PJDB\\Backup\\Database.bak", DeviceType.File);
// define "file relocation" - for all "logical" files in a SQL Server database,
// define a new physical location where the file will end up at          
RelocateFile relocateDataFile = new RelocateFile("Database", "\\\\srv-vm\\PJDB\\Backup" + "\\Database.mdf");
RelocateFile relocateLogFile = new RelocateFile("Database_log", "\\\\srv-vm\\PJDB\\Backup" + "\\Database_log.ldf");

_dataBase.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateDataFile);
_dataBase.RelocateFiles.Add(relocateLogFile);
_dataBase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
_dataBase.SqlRestore(server);
_dataBase.NoRecovery = false;
```

Comment: How you take a backup from DB? Are you copy ldf and mdf files or execute backup commands?

Comment: I execute backup command in my C# program

Comment: `mdf` and `ldf` aren't backup files, they're the actual database files. You want the `bak` and `trn` files when you created the database/log backups

Comment: Our SQL Server at work allows user to De-Attach the database and Re-Attach the database.    Once the database is De-Attached you can copy the mdf file.  I do this all the time to make backups of the database, and test the database without affecting other users (expect the short period of time to make the copies).  I don't normally work locally.  Instead I attach the original mdf file and the copy (under a different name) and test the copy.

Comment: Yes but i cannot execute the restoration method using a .bak store on my local machine. The restoration method use the connection to the sql server db

Comment: Can i De-attach and re-attach db using C# method ? @jdweng

Comment: Check this question's answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942207/how-can-i-backup-a-remote-sql-server-database-to-a-local-drive

Comment: Detaching and moving the files to a different server isn't backing up, nor is it restoring...

Comment: The De-Attach and Re-Attach solution cannot works there are people using the DB and i can't de-attach a used db

Comment: Yes.  I would first test commands using SQL Server Management Studio before trying with c#.  Find database with explorer and then right click database and select "deattach".  To attach open a new query window and do following : CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]
ON
(NAME = <database_name>,
    FILENAME = ‘<full path and database file name>’)
LOG ON
(NAME = <log_name>,
    FILENAME = ‘<full path and log file name>’)
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
  The same can be done using c# with a sqlclient ExecuteNonQuery command.

Comment: And you cannot copy a database that is in use either. You need to perform a backup and use the backup files. Those files ***aren't*** `mdf` and `ldf` files. Those are the database and transaction log files being used by the running database.

Comment: @jdweng Be sure to use SA when invoking sp_detach_db. Calling it with a Windows authenticated connection will change the file system ACLs on the .mdf and .ldf files which sometimes causes massive headaches when moving the files around or trying to reattach them.

Comment: @Larnu I perform a backup file, but i need on my local computer the `.mdf` and `.ldf`. If i locally copy the backup file, i cannot perform the restoration because the SQL server  will not have access to my backup file

Comment: You need to put the backup file somewhere the SQL Server Service Account has access to, @Nicolas . Don't go copying the `mdf` and `ldf` files.

Comment: Ok so I have to set up a shared file for each of the 50 pc's? Isn't there a way to set up access permissions on `.mdf` and `.ldf` files in order to just run a copy process? @Larnu

Comment: Put them in a network drive. If you deattach the mdf/ldf, I haven't seen any access issues.  I only have seen access issues when the mdf/ldf were created using archive.

Comment: Even if I put them in a network drive and have access to the files, I don't have the rights to open them and therefore exploit them. I Always need administrator access, there's no way to get rid of these restrictions ?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the msdn doc[Restore database to a new location; optionally rename the database using T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-to-a-new-location-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#restore-database-to-a-new-location-optionally-rename-the-database-using-t-sql) to know how to use T-SQL to do it.