# Writing to disk on mac/linux using SQL Server Command Line tools

Tags: sql-server, database, command-line, backup, sqlcmd

My objective is to backup a remote SQL Server database using SQL Server command line tools for Mac (or Linux). After installing the [`sqlcmd` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15), I am able to connect to the database but am not sure how to handle the TO DISK command, whose default is to assume a Windows operating system.

```
sqlcmd -S myserver.com -U AIS -Q "BACKUP DATABASE mydb TO DISK = N'/mybackups/mydb.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'mydb', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

This command returns the error:

> Cannot open backup device 'D:\BACKUP\mybackups\mydb.bak'. Operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified).

I have tried changing access permissions of the folder `mybackups` using `chmod 777 mybackups` but the same error is still thrown. Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: You are aware that `BACKUP TO DISK` refers to the SQL Server's local disk, not yours (the client)?

Comment: I was not aware of that; how does one move a backup from a SQL Server local disk then?

Comment: By copying the files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I backup a remote SQL Server database to a local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942207/how-can-i-backup-a-remote-sql-server-database-to-a-local-drive)